# How to use pyfig module in python?

Tags: python, svn

This is the part of the mailer.py script:

```
config = pyfig.Pyfig(config_file) 
svnlook = config.general.svnlook #svnlook path
sendmail = config.general.sendmail #sendmail path
From = config.general.from_email #from email address
To = config.general.to_email #to email address
```

what does this config variable contain? Is there a way to get the value for config variable without pyfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case config = a pyfig.Pyfig **object** initialised with the contents of the file named by the content of the string config_file.

To find out what that object does and contains you can either look at the documentation and/or the source code, both [here](https://bitbucket.org/alecwh/pyfig/), or you can print out, after the initialisation, e.g.:

```
config = pyfig.Pyfig(config_file) 
print "Config Contains:\n\t", '\n\t'.join(dir(config))
if hasattr(config, "keys"):
   print "Config Keys:\n\t", '\n\t'.join(config.keys())
```

or *if you are using Python 3*,

```
config = pyfig.Pyfig(config_file) 
print("Config Contains:\n\t", '\n\t'.join(dir(config)))
if hasattr(config, "keys"):
   print("Config Keys:\n\t", '\n\t'.join(config.keys()))
```

To get the same data without `pyfig` you would need to read and parse at the content of the file referenced by config_file within your own code.

**N.B.**: Note that pyfig seems to be more or less abandoned - no updates in over 5 years, web site no longer exists, etc., so I would strongly recommend converting the code to use a [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) configuration file instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please tell me what's the join method used for? Is it for concatenation?

Comment: _somestring_.join(_list_) will give a single string with all of the members of the list joined together with the string as a separator.  In this case it will put a newline and tab between them.

Comment: Understood :D Thank you :)